# Elixir: Transforming a deeply nested api response to a map

Tags: elixir

What would be the best way to parse an api response like the one below, into the desired format? Usually I would use Enum.reduce, but because there are lists nested inside the maps, I'm not sure how I can go about building up the accumulator.

```
api_resonse = 
    [
     %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => "api-app"}},
       "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources = %{}, image" => "gcr"}]},
       "status" =>[%{"type" => "updated", "state" => %{"running"}}]
      },
     %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => "user-app"}},
       "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources = %{}, image" => "dcr"}]},
       "status" =>[%{"type" => "updated", "state" => %{"running"}}]
      },
     %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => "admin-app"}},
       "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources = %{}, image" => "gcr"}]},
       "status" =>[%{"type" => "updated", "state" => %{"failed"}}]
      }
    ]


expected output =
    %{
      "api-app" => %{ "image" => "gcr", "state" => "running"}, 
      "user-app" => %{ "image" => "dcr", "state" => "running"},
      "admin-app" => %{ "image" => "gcr", "state" => "failed"}
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enum.map/2` and pattern matching. There were some syntax errors so I changed the input slightly.

```
api_response =
    [
     %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => "api-app"}},
       "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources" => %{}, "image" => "gcr"}]},
       "status" =>[%{"type" => "updated", "state" => "running"}]
      },
     %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => "user-app"}},
       "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources" => %{}, "image" => "dcr"}]},
       "status" =>[%{"type" => "updated", "state" => "running"}]
      },
     %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => "admin-app"}},
       "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources" => %{}, "image" => "gcr"}]},
       "status" =>[%{"type" => "updated", "state" => "failed"}]
      }
    ]

api_response
|> Enum.map(fn
  %{"meta" => %{"labels" => %{"app" => app}},
    "spec" => %{"container" => [%{"resources" => %{}, "image" => image}]},
    "status" => [%{"type" => "updated", "state" => state}]} ->
      {app, %{"image" => image, "state" => state}}
end)
|> Map.new
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
%{"admin-app" => %{"image" => "gcr", "state" => "failed"},
  "api-app" => %{"image" => "gcr", "state" => "running"},
  "user-app" => %{"image" => "dcr", "state" => "running"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That also can be easily achieved using [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html)

```elixir
for m <- api_response, into: %{} do
  {
     get_in(m, ~w|meta labels app|),
     %{
       "image" => get_in(m, ["spec", "container", Access.all(), "image"]),
       "state" => get_in(m, ["status", Access.all(), "state"])
     }
  }
end

#⇒ %{
#    "admin-app" => %{"image" => ["gcr"], "state" => ["failed"]},
#    "api-app" => %{"image" => ["gcr"], "state" => ["running"]},
#    "user-app" => %{"image" => ["dcr"], "state" => ["running"]}
#  }
```